# Audit account logon events Policy in Windows server 2012 auto change to No auditing frequently

Tags: windows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AkHv.jpg)

In windows server 2012 R2, I checked the boxes of Audit these attempts: Success , Failure , then the Security Setting of this policy is in "Success, Failure" status. But after around 10 muinutes, the status was changed to "No auditing" automatically and the boxes were unchecked. I checked the DC local policy was not overritten by global policy. And other DCs in my domain did not have this problem. Does anyone have idea or encountered similar situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below articles are about how to Audit account logon events, which may be helpful to you:

[Audit account logon events](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976367.aspx)

[Enable Active Directory Logon/Logoff Audit events](http://www.morgantechspace.com/2013/10/enable-active-directory-logonlogoff.html)

[Audit Successful Logon/Logoff and Failed Logons in Active Directory](https://www.lepide.com/blog/audit-successful-logon-logoff-and-failed-logons-in-activedirectory/)

Comment: Thanks. I have found a solution from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spatdsg/2011/06/06/audit-policy-not-registering-audits/